# Stripe: stripe don't have attribute "Charge"

Tags: django, stripe-payments, stripe-connect

I have this:

```
return stripe.Charge.create(
      amount=amount,
      currency=currency,
      source=source, # obtained with Stripe.js
      description=description
    )
```

and the answers is that:

```
File "/home/pdonaire1/desarrollos/4geeks/mall4g/apps/orders/stripe.py", line 16, in stripe_charge_create
    return stripe.Charge.create(
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Charge'
```

Note: I'm using Django, but with the shell works excelent, y don't know why with django don't work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have a `stripe` directory or `stripe.py` file so that when you type:

```
import stripe
```

this file or directory is imported in place of the real `stripe` module.

You can solve this by renaming the file/directory to anything else.